# Angular-material does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to implement an angular material app in reference to the 'Getting started' tutorial.

**style**

```
<link href="../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**scripts**

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script>
    // Include the dependency upon ngMaterial - important !!
    angular.module('starterApp', ['ngMaterial']);
</script>
```

I added a toolbar & button using `<md-toolbar>` & `<md-button>` as mentioned below:

```
 <md-toolbar class="md-menu-toolbar">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        Toolbar
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
<md-button class="md-fab" aria-label="FAB">
    button
</md-button>
```

but what I see is not angular material designs [click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfEe0.png)

Did I miss anything?

Comment: did you include angular library into the page?

Comment: Yes I did add angular library

Comment: and did you get any errors in Console?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: Have you put `ng-app="starterApp"` anywhere in your markup?

Comment: Yes I have attached ng-app="starterApp" to the html tag. All the script/style files are placed in the location as per the script/style tags but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for your question...

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('starterApp', ['ngMaterial']);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starterApp" ng-cloak>
<md-toolbar class="md-menu-toolbar">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        Toolbar
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
<md-button class="md-fab" aria-label="FAB">
    button
</md-button>
</body>
</html>
```